# Does querying a public BigQuery dataset counts towards project quota?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a Google Cloud Platform project that utilizes BigQuery in Sandbox mode (no billing enabled). In this project, I query solely public datasets.

The Quota (in IAM & admin) shows 0 MiB although I queried a few 100 GBs already.

This raises the question of whether or not querying public BigQuery datasets counts towards project quota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 1TB of data you query will be free. After that you will be billed at $5 per TB.

You can monitor your usage in logs, or I find using billing easier for this, you will get an exact usage figure, `Product` will be 'BigQuery', `SKU` will be 'Analysis'. If the data you were querying was not a public dataset you would also be charged for 'Active Storage'.

Relevant quote 1:

> You pay only for the queries that you perform on the data (the first 1 TB per month is free, subject to query pricing details).

And 2:

> To get started using a BigQuery public dataset, you must create or select a project. The first terabyte of data processed per month is free, so you can start querying public datasets without enabling billing. If you intend to go beyond the free tier, you must also enable billing.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/

Comment: I cannot use the billing view as I am using Sandbox mode were billing mode is not enabled.

Where can I find the logs view?

Comment: @DanielM you can find them in Stackdriver logging by filtering to BigQuery. Then you are looking for `Bigquery` `getqueryresults` logs. Within the JSON array you want `{protoPayload: { serviceData: { jobGetQueryResultsResponse: { job: { jobStatistics: { totalBilledBytes: ...`. The billing view is significantly simpler.

Comment: Ok, found it. However, the `totalBilledBytes` only appears on `jobcompleted` logs.